# How to import quoted data from a CSV file using mysqlimport?

Tags: mysql, csv, mariadb, schema, mysqlimport

How do I import [quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64954740/4531180) data as:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/csv$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/csv$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 59
Server version: 10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~focal-log mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> 
MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| foo                |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> 
MariaDB [(none)]> use foo;
Database changed
MariaDB [foo]> 
MariaDB [foo]> show tables;
Empty set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [foo]> 
MariaDB [foo]> mysqlimport --local --fields-terminated-by="," --fields-enclosed-by="\"" foo.bar labs.csv;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqlimport --local --fields-terminated-by="," --fields-enclosed-by="\"" foo....' at line 1
MariaDB [foo]> 
MariaDB [foo]> exit
Bye
nicholas@mordor:~/csv$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/csv$ head labs.csv 
"Date","Region","New_Tests","Total_Tests","Positivity","Turn_Around"
2020-01-23,"BC",2,2,0,32
2020-01-23,"Fraser",0,0,0,0
2020-01-23,"Interior",0,0,0,0
2020-01-23,"Northern",0,0,0,0
2020-01-23,"Unknown",0,0,0,0
2020-01-23,"Vancouver Coastal",2,2,0,32
2020-01-23,"Vancouver Island",0,0,0,0
2020-01-25,"BC",4,6,0,68
2020-01-25,"Fraser",3,3,0,72
nicholas@mordor:~/csv$
```

into either `mariadb` or `MySQL` using the console as here.

Preferably employing the `mysqlimport` utility, although if there's a nifty alternate tool, I wouldn't be opposed.

Do I need to create the dable first?  Was looking for the utility to parse the `CSV` file and infer the `schema`.

Comment: use `mysqlimport` from the prompt, not within `mysql`.

Comment: Have you tried it without putting the double quotes around the options? Ie: `fields-terminated-by=,`

Comment: `csvsql --db mysql://root:password@localhost/foo --insert --tables labs_table  labs.csv` worked.